Почему выходит ошибка? Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка прочиталась?
from pytube import YouTube

video_link = YouTube('https://youtu.be/vXTOCrrKD50?si=NnGcfA9EQYnh4Pn-')

print(video_link.title())

Ошибка:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ramazan0408/Рабочий стол/Videos/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(video_link.title()) 
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable


как задать хороший вопрос

Что делать с ответами на вопрос?

title - это не функция, а свойство. Нужно так:
print(video_link.title)


вот я невнимательный. В документации показалось, что там есть скобки. Спасибо.

Хорошим спасибом будет оценка ответа ;)

@МаксимСмирнов   Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете,
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour
